# Super capacitor charging circuit

Tags: charging, supercapacitor

I am trying to build a circuit to power a system for about 30s-1min after we have a power loss (12V going off), so my microcontroller and radio transmitter can send a message alerting the power loss.

For the charging part, my circuit holds the maximum nominal current of 0.5A and the current circuit is running at 0.15A.

I came up with this circuit:

[image]

Will I face some heat problems with R5 or the Zener D1? Any recommendations?

Comment: What is your circuit intended on doing? What do the components represent?

Comment: This question, and your simulation, need more detail. I suspect also you have wider questions than just heating in D1 and R5, but without knowing the zener voltage of D1, and the power rating of R5 this is unanswerable.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the inputs and outputs swapped, as currently the circuit makes no sense. But a lot of info is missing. How much is the voltage allowed to drop during 30-60 seconds? However, for 30 seconds and 0.2A, you need 6F capacitor for 1V voltage drop, and 1F for 6V voltage drop. Add the remaining info.